# Random Monster Generator in simple Text Based RPG

Tags: javascript, text, random

I'm trying to create a little text based rpg to put in practice what i learned of javascript. I tried two approaches, one is working and the other one isn't it, and I want to know why.

In the first one, I created an object "monster" with a method that sets all the properties of each monster (hit points, attack points, etc). The problem with this it's i have to write the properties one by one, and it makes the code too long for my taste.

```js
/* Write JavaScript here */
/* Write JavaScript here */
$(document).ready(function() {

 var hero = {
  hitPoints: 13,
  armorClass: 10,
  attackBonus: 1,
  weaponDamage: 7,
  heroStats: function() {
   return "Hero" + "<br/>" +
    "Hit Points: " + this.hitPoints + "<br/>" +
    "Armor Class: " + this.armorClass + "<br/>" +
    "Attack Bonus: " + this.attackBonus + "<br/>" +
    "Weapon Damage: " + this.weaponDamage;
  },
  alive: true
 };

 var monster = {
  name: "",
  hitPoints: 0,
  armorClass: 0,
  attackBonus: 0,
  weaponDamage: 0,
  monsterStats: function() {
   return this.name + "<br/>" +
    "Hit Points: " + this.hitPoints + "<br/>" +
    "Armor Class: " + this.armorClass + "<br/>" +
    "Attack Bonus: " + this.attackBonus + "<br/>" +
    "Weapon Damage: " + this.weaponDamage;
  },
  monsterSelected: false,
  selectMonster: function() {
   if (this.monsterSelected === false) {
    switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1) {
     case 1:
      this.name = "Werewolf";
      this.hitPoints = 20;
      this.armorClass = 8;
      this.attackBonus = 4;
      this.weaponDamage = 3;
      this.monsterSelected = true;
      break;
     case 2:
      this.name = "Goblin";
      this.hitPoints = 15;
      this.armorClass = 10;
      this.attackBonus = 4;
      this.weaponDamage = 3;
      this.monsterSelected = true;
      break;
    }
   }
  },
  alive: true
 };

 monster.selectMonster();
 $(".hero_info").html(hero.heroStats());
 $(".monster_info").html(monster.monsterStats());

 $("button").click(function() {
  battle(monster);
 });



 function battle(actualmonster) {
  if (actualmonster.alive === false) {
   actualmonster.monsterSelected = false;
   actualmonster.selectMonster();
   $(".monster_info").html(actualmonster.monsterStats());
   $(".battle_info").html("");
   actualmonster.alive = true;
  } else {
   var d20 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
   var d_wp = Math.floor(Math.random() * hero.weaponDamage) + 1;
   if (d20 + hero.attackBonus > actualmonster.armorClass) {
    $(".battle_info").html("You attack!: d20+" + hero.attackBonus + ": " + (d20 + hero.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + actualmonster.armorClass + "<br/>" + "You hit!: d" + hero.weaponDamage + ": " + d_wp);
    actualmonster.hitPoints = actualmonster.hitPoints - d_wp;
    $(".monster_info").html(actualmonster.monsterStats());
   } else {
    $(".battle_info").html("You miss!: d20+" + hero.attackBonus + ": " + (d20 + hero.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + actualmonster.armorClass);
   }
   if (actualmonster.hitPoints <= 0) {
    actualmonster.hitPoints = 0;
    $(".monster_info").html(actualmonster.monsterStats());
    $(".battle_info").html("You killed the monster!");
    actualmonster.alive = false;
   } else {
    var d20_m = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    var d_wp_m = Math.floor(Math.random() * monster.weaponDamage) + 1;
    if (d20_m + actualmonster.attackBonus > hero.armorClass) {
     $(".battle_info").append("<br/>Monster attacks you!: d20+" + actualmonster.attackBonus + ": " + (d20_m + actualmonster.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + hero.armorClass + "<br/>" + "Monster hits you!: d" + actualmonster.weaponDamage + ": " + d_wp_m);
     hero.hitPoints = hero.hitPoints - d_wp_m;
     $(".hero_info").html(hero.heroStats());
    } else {
     $(".battle_info").append("<br/>Monster miss!: d20+" + hero.attackBonus + ": " + (d20_m + monster.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + hero.armorClass);
    }
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p class="monster_info"></p>
  <p class="battle_info"></p>
  <p class="hero_info"></p>
  <button type="button">Attack</button>
  </body>
```

In the second one, instead of creating and object "monster", i make a constructor, so i could define the monsters in a shorter and simplier way (for example: var phantom = new monster (prop1, prop2, prop3...)). The issue comes when i tried select a random monster for each battle. I tried a lot of things, but the problem remains the same: if a create a random function to select the monsters, this works every time a click the attack button, making a mess. This is driven me crazy, and i have no idea what to do. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hero = {
        hitPoints: 13,
        armorClass: 10,
        attackBonus: 1,
        weaponDamage: 7,
        heroStats: function() {
            return "Hero" + "<br/>" +
                "Hit Points: " + this.hitPoints + "<br/>" +
                "Armor Class: " + this.armorClass + "<br/>" +
                "Attack Bonus: " + this.attackBonus + "<br/>" +
                "Weapon Damage: " + this.weaponDamage;
        },
        alive: true
    };

    function monster(name, hitpoints, armorclass, attackbonus, weapondamage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hitPoints = hitpoints;
        this.armorClass = armorclass;
        this.attackBonus = attackbonus;
        this.weaponDamage = weapondamage;
        this.monsterStats = function() {
                return this.name + "<br/>" +
                    "Hit Points: " + this.hitPoints + "<br/>" +
                    "Armor Class: " + this.armorClass + "<br/>" +
                    "Attack Bonus: " + this.attackBonus + "<br/>" +
                    "Weapon Damage: " + this.weaponDamage;
            },
            this.selected = false;
        this.alive = true;
    }

    function selectMonster() {
        var werewolf = new monster("Werewolf", 5, 4, 4, 3);
        var goblin = new monster("Goblin", 15, 4, 4, 3);
        switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1) {
            case 1:
                if (werewolf.selected === false) {
                    werewolf.selected = false;
                    return werewolf;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (goblin.selected === false) {
                    goblin.selected = false;
                    return goblin;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    $(".hero_info").html(hero.heroStats());
    $(".monster_info").html(selectMonster().monsterStats());

    $("button").click(function() {
        battle(selectMonster());
    });



    function battle(actualmonster) {
        if (actualmonster.alive === false) {
            actualmonster.selected = false;
            actualmonster.selectMonster();
            $(".monster_info").html(actualmonster.monsterStats());
            $(".battle_info").html("");
            actualmonster.alive = true;
        } else {
            var d20 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
            var d_wp = Math.floor(Math.random() * hero.weaponDamage) + 1;
            if (d20 + hero.attackBonus > actualmonster.armorClass) {
                $(".battle_info").html("You attack!: d20+" + hero.attackBonus + ": " + (d20 + hero.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + actualmonster.armorClass + "<br/>" + "You hit!: d" + hero.weaponDamage + ": " + d_wp);
                actualmonster.hitPoints = actualmonster.hitPoints - d_wp;
                $(".monster_info").html(actualmonster.monsterStats());
            } else {
                $(".battle_info").html("You miss!: d20+" + hero.attackBonus + ": " + (d20 + hero.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + actualmonster.armorClass);
            }
            if (actualmonster.hitPoints <= 0) {
                actualmonster.hitPoints = 0;
                $(".monster_info").html(actualmonster.monsterStats());
                $(".battle_info").html("You killed the monster!");
                actualmonster.alive = false;
            } else {
                var d20_m = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
                var d_wp_m = Math.floor(Math.random() * hero.weaponDamage) + 1;
                if (d20_m + actualmonster.attackBonus > hero.armorClass) {
                    $(".battle_info").append("<br/>Monster attacks you!: d20+" + actualmonster.attackBonus + ": " + (d20_m + actualmonster.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + hero.armorClass + "<br/>" + "Monster hits you!: d" + actualmonster.weaponDamage + ": " + d_wp_m);
                    hero.hitPoints = hero.hitPoints - d_wp_m;
                    $(".hero_info").html(hero.heroStats());
                } else {
                    $(".battle_info").append("<br/>Monster miss!: d20+" + hero.attackBonus + ": " + (d20_m + actualmonster.attackBonus) + " vs AC " + hero.armorClass);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="monster_info"></p>
  <p class="battle_info"></p>
  <p class="hero_info"></p>
  <button type="button">Attack</button>
```

Comment: Halcyon I think your edits changed part of the code that might have been breaking and my answer no longer makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is good but you're using it weird. `selectMonster` will randomly generate monster with some random logic and a call to `new monster`. But then you call `selectMonster()` a few times for no apparent reason.

Your code should look like:

```
var current_monster = selectMonster(); // note that you already have function named monster
$(".monster_info").html(current_monster.monsterStats());

$("button").click(function() {
    battle(current_monster);
});
```

You can also go all the way with prototyping to define your monsters:

```
function Monster(name, hp, attack) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.alive = true;
    // etc
}
Monster.prototype.monsterStats = function() {
    return this.name + "<br/>" +
        "Hit Points: " + this.hitPoints + "<br/>" +
        "Armor Class: " + this.armorClass + "<br/>" +
        "Attack Bonus: " + this.attackBonus + "<br/>" +
        "Weapon Damage: " + this.weaponDamage;
}

function Werewolf() {
    Monster.call(this, "werewolf", 5, 4); // call parent
}
Werewolf.prototype = new Monster();

function Goblin() {
    Monster.call(this, "goblin", 15, 3); // call parent
}
Goblin.prototype = new Monster();

var goblin = new Goblin();
console.log(goblin.hp); // 15
console.log(goblin.monsterStats()); // goblin <br /> etc..
```

Comment: Good. I tried and it works fine, the problem now is when the battle finishes, and I click the button, the monster its the same. Maybe I wasn't explicit enough before (my bad): after each battle finishes, a new one starts, and the new monster should be a random one. You can see this in the first code (just change the monster's hitPoints to 1, so you have not to wait all the battle).

Comment: Also, why is better to go with prototyping and not just with the constructor function? It seems to me shorter and easier to go with the constructor.

Comment: Prototyping is not strictly better than creation functions. It works well in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

In your monster constructor, you're doing stuff in your return statement that you probably don't want to be. When you have something like `return x + 1, foo = 3, bar = false`  the expressions are evaluated left to right and the *last* one is returned. That is, you're retuning the state of `this.alive` instead of returning the `this` expected in the constructor.

Try refactoring your code to explicitly return the monster object you want to be created by the constructor, and see if you still have problems there. Generally, you want your return to stand on its own, to avoid confusion around syntax.

Comment: I'm not following you very well. I don't see what's the problem you said; the return stament works fine to me (the monster's states are showed correctly). Can you explain a little more? Thanks.